# Egit listed every file that was built in compare view after I run Ant to build the project

Tags: eclipse, egit

Guys:

I would know how to set up Eclipse so I can compare with my local project with head revision on remote server with EGit. Here is the situation: I imported a new  project with Egit smoothly. However, I want to compare with head revision or a commit with my local project after I did some change. To my surprise, the eclipse listed every file in Build directory after I run ant to build the project. The file that I really updated was not even listed in compare with view. I attach a screen snapshot to show what is going on. Can anybody tell me how to set up compare with in eclipse?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Sam

Comment: Did it work correctly with your repository before? Does your repository's `.gitignore` file mention the `build/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

Delete the .gitignore file (if present)in your directory. Refresh
Add files to Index.

The .gitignore specifies the pattern which will decide whether to ignore a path.

Note: Deleting the .gitignore is harmles and will show each and every change made in your repository including whitespaces.

Adding files to Index: will check for the new files and changes made, stages these files.

Thank You. I hope this will be helpful to you.